# Why my `xxx.bat` job quit after system come from sleep ? How to keep it through sleep?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

It is a udp tunnel tool https://github.com/wangyu-/udp2raw-tunnel

bat file content:

```
@REM @Author: XXX
@REM @Date:   2019-10-06 10:46:46
@REM @Last Modified by:   XXX
@REM Modified time: 2020-03-20 20:18:18

D:\udp2raw_windows\udp2raw_mp_nolibnet -c -l 127.0.0.1:3333  -r xxxxxxx:xxxx -k "xxxxx" --raw-mode faketcp   --cipher-mode xor
```

Everytime after system come back from sleep, I found the running cmd window of this bat was gone. Have to restart it .

Other command-line job mannually running in cmd doesn't quit at all .